# SQL Data Range Min Max category

Tags: sql, range, max, break, min

I want to determine the range of 2 categories. Category A and Category B. A starts from 1 to 15, B starts from 16 to 31 then A Again starts from 32 to 40.
Now If run this query

```
select min(range), max(range) 
from table
group by category
order by category
```

it gives me Range of category A from 1 to 40 and Category B from 16 to 31. I want to break the Range and want to see the results

```
Category A 1 to 15
Category B 16 to 31
Category A 32 to 40
```

How do I do that? Do I need a 3rd column? I know if i have 3rd column with new categories lets say C D E respectively, I can group by those and get the results. but I dont know how to do that.

Please help me out.

Thanks
-Adeel

Comment: What are the criteria that you are using for determining the appropriate ranges?  In particular, are the ranges necessarily sequences of integers?  That is, if the first range were missing "8", would it be one range or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to break the categories into groups consisting of consecutive integers, then the following will work:

```
select category, diff, min(range), max(range)
from 
(
   select category, range,
      (range - row_number() over (partition by category order by range)) as diff
   from table
) t
group by category
order by 1, 3
```

This query is based on the observation that within a given grouping for a category, the numbers increase sequentially.  Hence, subtracting a sequence of integer will result in a constant, which can then be used for identifying that particular range.

`Row_Number()` is a standard SQL function, so it is available in most databases.

Comment: Hi Gordon. This is very good example and I will try it now and let you know.

Comment: Gordon, I just tried your code and it worked like a charm. I'm so happy. :D

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) should work for you, but it depends on your RDBMS on how this could work (and if it is even supported) But, you could probably do some sort of incremental count that can be used as a multiplier for each piece up until a max limit. If you let us know the RDBMS I can provide an example.

Comment: Hi Justin, CTE are allowed and I can work on these. Please give me the example. Thanks