# Group sequential numbers into min and max group pairs

Tags: algorithm, plsql, grouping

I have a table with a list of numbers. Each number belongs to an entity.

```
Entity  Number 
1         1
1         2
1         3
1         4
    ...
1         20
2         21
2         22
2         23 
1         24
2         25
2         26 
2         30 
2         31
2         32
2         33
```

The goal is to list the numbers, grouped by the entities as ranges (min-max pairs).
I need to find a way to group the above table as:

```
Entity Min Max
1       1  20
2       21 23
1       24 24
2       25 26
2       30 33
```

I've succesfully done this in my education, but I always found it hard and can't remember how the algorithm was done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks similar to [SQL Data Range Min Max category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423781/sql-data-range-min-max-category)
and [TSQL Select Min & Max row when grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001783/tsql-select-min-max-row-when-grouping)

Comment: The second answer pointed me in the right direction, I couldn't find it myself. Much obliged